# How to get all values while passing Replace query

Tags: sql-server-2012

select Column(languages) from Table

Output :

Column(Languages)

1.Hindi,Tamil,Telugu,Kannada,Others
2.Others
3.Hindi
4.Hindi,Tamil,Telugu

(4 row(s) affected)

The Above query gives all the rows ,but the below queries gives no row.

select Column(languages) from Table
where languages like '%'+ Replace('Hindi,Tamil,Telugu,Kannada,Others',',','%'' OR a.languages LIKE ''%')+'%'

Output :

(0 row(s) affected)

How to get all rows for the above query......

Search criteria.....

Answer (score 0):

Although your question isn't very much clear, as per my understand you can try the below code :

```
SELECT Column(languages) from Table

UNION ALL

SELECT Column(languages) from Table where languages like '%'
```